# Getting 500 Error while calling webservice from google app engine

Tags: web-services, rest, google-app-engine, httpclient

I am trying to get the response from webservice- http://services.groupkt.com/state/get/IND/all  .It is working fine normally through java code but when I have deployed in google app engine it is returning 500 error.

Following one is the code.

```
try {

        // create HTTP Client
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();

        // Create new getRequest with below mentioned URL
        HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet("http://services.groupkt.com/state/get/IND/all");

        // Add additional header to getRequest which accepts application/xml data
        getRequest.addHeader("accept", "application/json");



        // Execute your request and catch response
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(getRequest);

        // Check for HTTP response code: 200 = success
        if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
        }

        // Get-Capture Complete application/xml body response
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((response.getEntity().getContent())));
        String output;
        System.out.println("============Output:============");

        // Simply iterate through XML response and show on console.
        while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(output);
        }

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I have searched it.It is showing as internal server error.How can i fix it?

Comment: Are you using App Engine Standard or Flexible?

Comment: How to know which App Engine I am using?

Comment: Do you have app.yaml or appengine-web.xml? If you have appengine-web.xml, does it have `<vm>true</vm>` inside it?

Comment: If i am keeping that tag,project is not deploying showing as checking availability 1 secs,checking availability 2 secs,...